# Create a Table of Contents in Corel Draw?

Tags: corel-draw, book, tables

Is there any way to create a **table of contents** for the catalog I am designing in Corel Draw X6 ?

Comment: InDesign will do what you need.

Answer (score 2):

> **No.** CorelDRAW is not intended for book work. However X6 has some
>   enhanced layout tools and features like text styles, baseline grid,
>   dynamic page numbering etc. But unfortunately ToC or subject index
>   cannot be yet done automatically.

[CorelDraw Forums](http://coreldraw.com/forums/t/34570.aspx)

Comment: thanks for your kind reply. may I ask what software would be good for my purpose?

Comment: Personally, I don't know of another program that would do this besides **MS Word** or maybe **Publisher**. Of course with those programs, you will loose a TON of flexibility as they are no where near Professional quality for print design.

Comment: @JohnGreen QuarkXPress would likely be a good choice, but it would require quite some learning I imagine.